# Not able to substitute { with a space { in vim

Tags: vim

I want to add a space before all of `{`.

```
specify{ expect(@intersection.check_size?). to eq false }
```

I tried the following but did not work.

```
:s%/\{/ \{/g
```

According to [this website](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace), I need to escape `{`.

It gives errors.

```
E554 Syntax error in \{...}
E870 (NFA regexp) Error reading repetition limits
E476 Invalid command
```

How can I replace `{` with `{`?

Comment: You misunderstood that wiki page. The `\{` in examples on that page are showing you how to use the special meaning of `\{X,Y\}` searches which specify the number of times to repeat what comes before it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to escape the `{`

```
:%s/{/ &/g
```

Comment: What is & mean here? Is it supposed to be a space{?

Comment: `&` in the analogous to `\0`. See `:h :s/\&`

Answer (score 1):

### magic

if you didn't set `magic` option, vim use default value : `magic` `(\m)`

with `magic`, `{` is literal `{`, `\{` gives it special meaning.

so you can either do `s/{/ &/g` or use `very magic` `s/\v\{/ &/g`.

`:h magic` you will find a table, list the differences of them.

### cmd format error

there is another error in your cmd `:s`, you should put the range `%` **before** `s` -> `:%s/.../.../g`